# Table inline styling looks different among browsers

Tags: html, css

I'm used to code with old  tags and trying to do it with inline CSS.

I have a table with **inline styling**. I tried to get a colored 1px border.
It looks like desired under FFox and Opera (border color #FFBF97) but IE11 shows a different border color (black.)

What am i doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<table border="1" bordercolor="#FFBF97" bordercolordark="#FFBF97" bordercolorlight="#FFBF97" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" background="x.png" style="border-collapse:collapse;table border:1px;border-color:#FFBF97;">
```

I tried to change
    style="border-collapse:collapse;table border:1px;border-color:#FFBF97;"

to:
    style="border-collapse:collapse;border-width:1px;border-color:#FFBF97;"

even:
    style="border-collapse:collapse;table border:1px #FFBF97;"

all of these gave the same result, FFox and Opera display 1px #FFBF97 border while IE11 shows a black 1px border.

Comment: Stick with CSS only. Presentational attributes like `bordercolor` are deprecated in HTML. There's no such property as `table border` (property names cannot have spaces). It should work to do `border: 1px solid #FFBF97;`.

Comment: Thank you very much Mike McCaughan.     border: 1px solid #FFBF97; worked perfectly. I need to learn a lot more. I keep presentational attributes for backward compatibility with ancient browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike McCaughan answered my question.

> Stick with CSS only. Presentational attributes like bordercolor are deprecated in HTML. There's no such property as table border (property names cannot have spaces). It should work to do border: 1px solid #FFBF97;. – Mike McCaughan Jul 5 at 13:47